# image selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a website that has a drop-down menu allowing users to select an item, an image will appear with a caption. I can't seem to figure out how to get this working. I have a blank paragraph tag that appends the image into the document.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>A JavaScript Template Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/HTML; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        What kind of mood are you in today?
    </p>
    <select name="menu" id="menu"> //dropdown menu
        <option value="1">
            Choose your option
        </option>
        <option value="2">
            Happy
        </option>
        <option value="3">
            Angry
        </option>
        <option>
            Sad
        </option>
        <option>
            Grumpy
        </option>
    </select>
    <p id="img-swap">

    </p>
    <h1 id="captions"></h1>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In `script.js`

```
var img = ['empty', 'happy', 'angry', 'sad', 'grumpy'];
var im = [];
var sayings = ['How are you feeling today?', 'Happy cat is happy', 'Angry cat is angry', 'Sad cat is sad', 'Grumpy cat is grumpy'];

function imgSwap() {
    var checkIndex = $('#selector').prop('selectedIndex');
    if (index === 0) {
        $('#img-swap').hide();
    } else {
        $('#img-swap').html('<img src="images/' + img[index] + '.jpg" width="600px" height="400px" alt="cats">').hide().show();
        }
        $('#captions').html(sayings[index]);
    }
    $(function() {
    for (var i = 1; i < img.length; i++) {
        im[i] = new Image();
        im[i].src='images/' + img[i] +'.jpg'
        }
        $('#selector').change(function() {
        swap_pictures();
    });
});
```

Comment: And where is this `'#selector'`?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to have the function run by employing jQuery's `change()` function.

Here's a trimmed down and working JSFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/UckER/ - I only included the code necessary to change the images. You may need to tweak it some, but this should put you on the right track. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

You have some pretty obvious mistakes in your code. Here are some of the basic ones I could find in first look at your code:

1. Your jQuery is defined on `#selector` when nothing with that id is present in the code. It should be:

   ```
   <select name="menu" id="selector">
   ```
2. In your `.change()` method, you are calling `swap_pictures()` function, while you've defined the function as `imgSwap()`.
3. In the `imgSwap` function, you are setting the value for `checkIndex` variable, but later in the if condition; you have

   ```
   if (index === 0) {
   ```

   where `index` is again undefined variable.

---

### EDIT

I gues that was pretty much all of it. fixing them all resulted in this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nBVuw/)